# PHP does not output isset array from Mysql. Although through print_r the array is displayed

Tags: php, mysql

The `Mysql` command is set correctly, since the data is displayed correctly via `print_r($ads)`. I pack the resulting array into `$ads`

Catch `id`

```
$id = htmlentities($_GET['id']);
```

Query DB.

```
SELECT
     rent.id, 
     rent.run,
     rent.year,
   FROM rent
     WHERE rent.id = '.$id.'
          ORDER BY rent.time_upload DESC');
```

But through the `isset` function, they are not shown, no errors are displayed, nothing, just a blank page.

I output the data like this

```
<?php if (isset($ads)): ?>

      <h3> 
 
          <?=$ads['id'];?> 
             <?=$ads['run'];?>
                    <?=$ads['year'];?>  

 
      </h3>
          
<?php endif; ?>
```

`short_tags` are included in PHP.

Please help solve the problem.

Comment: Could you show us the output of `print_r($ads)`?

Comment: `isset` isn't really meant to output anything, and doesn't modify your array. I'm assuming your query returns an array which contains arrays of records, and you are not accessing the records properly.

Comment: Oh, and can you show the part of the code where you create $ads? It could be you're making an object instead of an array, or are using a mysqli results object directly...

Comment: @Stevish  Array
(
    [3625] => Array  (
            [run] => 31580
             [year] => 2020
        )

)

Comment: a blank page would suggest a 500 error, check the error log.

Comment: and htmlentities is not for protecting against SQL injection

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone   thnx for immediatly help!  Be health!

Comment: @Stevish  thnx for immediatly help!  Be health!

Comment: np happy coding: https://3v4l.org/UuiU3

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements with placeholder values** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: tadman@   big Thanks!

I have to check, if the ID is not a number, then the code is not executed and I use ORM for prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going deep enough. `$ads['run']` doesn't exist, only `$ads['3625']['run']` does. Try:

```
<?php
foreach( $ads as $ad ) {
    ?>
    <h3> 

      <?=$ad['id'];?> 
         <?=$ad['run'];?>
                <?=$ad['year'];?>  


  </h3>
  <?php
 }
```

Comment: And, as @Lawrence Cherone said, please don't rely on `$id = htmlentities($_GET['id']);` to validate your SQL. Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please look into "Preventing MySQL injection" and read an article or three about it.

Comment: Thank you so much brother on the code)) You saved me so much time !!! I wish you health and great results!   I'm using ORM RedBean and of course its only a little piece of code.

Comment: If you're using RedBean there should be absolutely no reason to inject `$id` in there like that. It [supports placeholder values](https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/querying), so use `:id`, then `[ ':id' => $id ]` as a secondary argument in your execution. `htmlentities` is for preventing XSS bugs, **not** SQL injection. It only causes problems in the SQL context.

Comment: @tadman Can you please write the code of it??? In php im new. How it suppose to be with my query?

Comment: There's dozens of examples in that link I provided.

Comment: @ tadman  i've  made the example. But it's nit working...             WHERE rent.id= :id' [':id' => '$id']);   or this making in htmlentities???